# Training accuracy while fitting the model not reflected in confusion matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am training an image classification model to classify certain images containing mountain, waterfall and people classes. Currently, I am using Vgg-net (transfer learning) to train this data. While training, I am getting almost 93% accuracy on training data and 90% accuracy on validation data. However, when I want to check the classes being wrongly classified during training by using confusion matrix on the training data, the accuracy seems to be much less. Only about 30% of the data is classified correctly.

I have tried checking the confusion matrix on other similar image classification problems but there it seems to be showing the accuracy that we see while training.

Code to create ImageDataGenerator objects for training and validation

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
#Train DataSet Generator with Augmentation
print("\nTraining Data Set")
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train_flow = train_generator.flow(
    train_images, train_labels,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
)

#Validation DataSet Generator with Augmentation
print("\nValidation Data Set")
val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
val_flow = val_generator.flow(
    validation_images,validation_labels,
    batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
)
```

Code to build the model and compile it

```
# Initialize InceptionV3 with transfer learning
base_model = applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', 
                                include_top=False, 
                                input_shape=(WIDTH, HEIGHT,3))

# add a global spatial average pooling layer
x = base_model.output

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
# and a dense layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(len(categories), activation='softmax')(x)

# first: train only the top layers (which were randomly initialized)
# i.e. freeze all convolutional InceptionV3 layers
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False


# this is the model we will train
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# compile the model (should be done *after* setting layers to non-trainable)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4), metrics=['accuracy'], loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.summary()
```

Code to fit the model to the training dataset and validate using validation dataset

```
import math
top_layers_file_path=r"/content/drive/My Drive/intel-image-classification/intel-image-classification/top_layers.iv3.hdf5"

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(top_layers_file_path, monitor='loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
tb = TensorBoard(log_dir=r'/content/drive/My Drive/intel-image-classification/intel-image-classification/logs', batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, write_graph=True, update_freq='batch')
early = EarlyStopping(monitor="loss", mode="min", patience=5)
csv_logger = CSVLogger(r'/content/drive/My Drive/intel-image-classification/intel-image-classification/logs/iv3-log.csv', append=True)

history = model.fit_generator(train_flow, 
                              epochs=30, 
                              verbose=1,
                              validation_data=val_flow, 
                              validation_steps=math.ceil(validation_images.shape[0]/BATCH_SIZE),                              
                              steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(train_images.shape[0]/BATCH_SIZE),
                              callbacks=[checkpoint, early, tb, csv_logger])
```

---

training steps show the following accuracy:

```
Epoch 1/30

91/91 [==============================] - 44s 488ms/step - loss: 0.6757 - acc: 0.7709 - val_loss: 0.4982 - val_acc: 0.8513

Epoch 2/30

91/91 [==============================] - 32s 349ms/step - loss: 0.4454 - acc: 0.8395 - val_loss: 0.3980 - val_acc: 0.8557

.
.

Epoch 20/30

91/91 [==============================] - 32s 349ms/step - loss: 0.2026 - acc: 0.9238 - val_loss: 0.2684 - val_acc: 0.8940

.
.

Epoch 30/30

91/91 [==============================] - 32s 349ms/step - loss: 0.1739 - acc: 0.9364 - val_loss: 0.2616 - val_acc: 0.8984
```

Ran predictions on the training dataset itself:

```
import math
import numpy as np
predictions = model.predict_generator(
    train_flow,
    verbose=1,
    steps=math.ceil(train_images.shape[0]/BATCH_SIZE))
predicted_classes = [x[0] for x in enc.inverse_transform(predictions)]
true_classes = [x[0] for x in enc.inverse_transform(train_labels)]
```

enc - OneHotEncoder

However, the confusion matrix looks like the following:

```
import sklearn

sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(
    true_classes, 
    predicted_classes,
    labels=['mountain','people','waterfall'])
```

Confusion Matrix (Could not upload a better looking picture)

```
  ([[315, 314, 283],

   [334, 309, 273],

   [337, 280, 263]])
```

The complete code has been uploaded on https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/paridhichoudhary/scene-image-classification/blob/master/Classification_v7.ipynb

Comment: It's 3 classes and accuracy is around 30%? You use correct preprocessing right?

Comment: Please post your `model.compile` statement

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen I have posted the pre-processing code in the question.

Comment: @desertnaut model.compile code added to the question

Comment: I mean, did you use the same preprocessing on `confusion_matrix`? How do you get that `predicted_classes`. What I saw many times is that people use some sort of preprocess(like `x/255.`) when train, but use the raw images when predict and result in a complete random output. Your predicted data has accuracy just like a random.

Comment: For example, when you call `model.predict(img)`, did you call `img = preprocess_input(img)` first?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen: I used the training ImageDataGenerator object itself to predict. Added the code to the question.

Comment: Very interesting indeed, could you put the wholde project to github?

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen added the link at the end of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because of the `train_generator.flow` has `shuffle=True` by [default](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py#L371). This result in `predicted_classes` doesn't match the `train_labels`.

Maybe set `shuffle=False` on `train_generator.flow` should help this, or instead use something like this might easier to understand.

```
predicted_classes = []
true_classes = []
for i in range(len(train_flow)):  # you can just use `len(train_flow)` instead of `math.ceil(train_images.shape[0]/BATCH_SIZE))`
    x, y = train_flow[i]  # you can use `train_flow[i]` like this
    z = model.predict(x)
    for j in range(x.shape[0]):
        predicted_classes.append(z[j])
        true_classes.append(y[j])
```

I didn't try this yet but it should work though.

Comment: Why no one votes this! Solved my question! Thanks